# Text Pre-processing + Python + CSV : Removing special characters from a column of a CSV

Tags: python, csv, text-classification, text-processing

I am working on a text classification problem. My CSV file contains a column called 'description' which describes events. Unfortunately, that column is full of special characters apart from English words. Sometimes the entire field in a row is full of such characters, or, sometimes, few words are of such special characters and the rest are English words. I am showing you two specimen fields of two different rows:

```
├á┬ñ┬╣├á┬ñ┬░ ├á┬ñ┬╡├á┬ñ┬░├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬╖ ├á┬ñΓÇó├á┬ÑΓé¼ ├á┬ñ┬ñ├á┬ñ┬░├á┬ñ┬╣ ├á┬ñΓÇí├á┬ñ┬╕ ├á┬ñ┬╡├á┬ñ┬░├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬╖ ├á┬ñ┬¡├á┬ÑΓé¼ ├á┬ñ┬╕├á┬ñ┬┐├á┬ñΓÇÜ├á┬ñ┬º├á┬Ñ┬ü ├á┬ñ┬╕├á┬ÑΓÇí├á┬ñ┬¿├á┬ñ┬╛ ├á┬ñ┬ª├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬╡├á┬ñ┬╛├á┬ñ┬░├á┬ñ┬╛ ├á┬ñΓÇá├á┬ñ┬»├á┬ÑΓÇ╣├á┬ñ┼ô├á┬ñ┬┐├á┬ñ┬ñ ├á┬ñ┬╕├á┬ñ┬┐├á┬ñΓÇÜ├á┬ñ┬º├á┬ÑΓé¼ ├á┬ñ┬¬├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬░├á┬ÑΓé¼├á┬ñ┬«├á┬ñ┬┐├á┬ñ┬»├á┬ñ┬░ ├á┬ñ┬▓├á┬ÑΓé¼├á┬ñΓÇö ├á┬ñ┬½├á┬Ñ┬ü├á┬ñ┼╕├á┬ñ┬¼├á┬ÑΓÇ░├á┬ñ┬▓ ├á┬ñ┼╕├á┬ÑΓÇÜ├á┬ñ┬░├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬¿├á┬ñ┬╛├á┬ñ┬«├á┬ÑΓÇí├á┬ñΓÇÜ├á┬ñ┼╕ ├á┬ñΓÇó├á┬ñ┬╛ ├á┬ñΓÇá├á┬ñ┬»├á┬ÑΓÇ╣├á┬ñ┼ô├á┬ñ┬¿ ├á┬ñ┬Å├á┬ñ┬«├á┬ñ┬¼├á┬ÑΓé¼├á┬ñ┬Å├á┬ñ┬« ├á┬ñΓÇö├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬░├á┬ñ┬╛├á┬ñΓÇ░├á┬ñΓÇÜ├á┬ñ┬í ├á┬ñ┬«├á┬ÑΓÇí├á┬ñΓÇÜ ├á┬ñΓÇó├á┬ñ┬░├á┬ñ┬¿├á┬ÑΓÇí ├á┬ñ┼ô├á┬ñ┬╛ ├á┬ñ┬░├á┬ñ┬╣├á┬ÑΓé¼ ├á┬ñ┬╣├á┬Ñ╦å ├á┬ñ┼ô├á┬ñ┬┐├á┬ñ┬╕├á┬ñ┬«├á┬ÑΓÇí├á┬ñΓÇÜ ├á┬ñΓÇª├á┬ñΓÇÜ├á┬ñ┬í├á┬ñ┬░-19 ├á┬ñ┼╕├á┬ÑΓé¼├á┬ñ┬«├á┬ÑΓÇí├á┬ñΓÇÜ ├á┬ñ┬¡├á┬ñ┬╛├á┬ñΓÇö ├á┬ñ┬▓├á┬ÑΓÇí├á┬ñ┬ñ├á┬ÑΓé¼ ├á┬ñ┬╣├á┬Ñ╦å ├á┬ñΓÇá├á┬ñ┬¬ ├á┬ñ┬╕├á┬ñ┬¡├á┬ÑΓé¼ ├á┬ñ┬╕├á┬ÑΓÇí ├á┬ñ┬¿├á┬ñ┬┐├á┬ñ┬╡├á┬ÑΓÇí├á┬ñ┬ª├á┬ñ┬¿ ├á┬ñ┬╣├á┬Ñ╦å ├á┬ñ┬╕├á┬ñ┬«├á┬ñ┬╛├á┬ñ┼ô ├á┬ñΓÇó├á┬ÑΓÇí ├á┬ñ┬»├á┬Ñ┬ü├á┬ñ┬╡├á┬ñ┬╛├á┬ñΓÇ£├á┬ñΓÇÜ ├á┬ñΓÇó├á┬ÑΓÇ╣ ├á┬ñ┬¬├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬░├á┬ÑΓÇ╣├á┬ñ┬ñ├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬╕├á┬ñ┬╛├á┬ñ┬╣├á┬ñ┬¿ ├á┬ñΓÇó├á┬ñ┬░├á┬ñ┬¿├á┬ÑΓÇí ├á┬ñΓÇª├á┬ñ┬╡├á┬ñ┬╢├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬» ├á┬ñ┬¬├á┬ñ┬º├á┬ñ┬╛├á┬ñ┬░├á┬ÑΓÇí├á┬ñΓÇÜ

Unwind on the strums of Guitar &  immerse your soul into the magical vibes of music! ├»┬╕┬Å? ├»┬╕┬Å?..Guitar Night By Ashmik Patil.July 19, 2018.Thursday.9 PM Onwards.*Cover charges applicable...#GuitarNight #MusicalNight #MagicalMusic #MusicLove #Party #Enjoy #TheBarTerminal #Mumbaikars #Mumbai
```

In the first one the entire field is full of such unreadable characters, whereas in the second case, only few such characters are present. Rest of them are English words.

I want to remove only those special chars keeping the English words as they are, as I need those English words to form a bag of words at a later stage.

How to implement that with Python ( I am using a jupyter notebook) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Assuming that you have been able to take out the text from the CSV file -

```
#python 2.7
import re
text = "Something with special characters á┬ñ┬╡├á┬ñ┬░├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬╖"
cleaned_text = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]+','', text)
print cleaned_text

Output - Something with special characters
```

To understand the regex expression used, [refer here](https://gist.github.com/jonlabelle/3893f6ac9447f7ee27fe).

Answer (score 2):

You can encode your string to `ascii` and `ignore` the errors.

```
>>> text = 'Something with special characters á┬ñ┬╡├á┬ñ┬░├á┬Ñ┬ì├á┬ñ┬╖'
>>> text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Which will give you a binary object, which you can further decode again to `utf`

```
>>> text
b'Something with special characters '

>>> text = text.decode('utf')
>>> text
'Something with special characters '
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas to read the csv file into a dataframe. using:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv(fileName,convertor={COLUMN_NUMBER:func})
```

where func, is a function that takes a single string and removes special characters.
this can be done in different ways, using regex, but here is a simple one

```
import string
def func(strg):
    return ''.join(c for c in strg if c in string.printable[:-5])
```

alternatively you can read the dataframe first then apply to alter the description column. ie.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
df['description'] = df['description'].apply(func)
```

or using regex

```
df['description'] = df['description'].str.replace('[^A-Za-z _]','')
```

> `string.printable[:-5 ]` is the set of characters '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ '

Comment: As I need only English words to form the bag of words, should I use this this regular expression "[A-Za-z]*" ? If I can, then what would be the modified version of your code?

Comment: if you prefer regex see the example I added

Comment: 1) Why are you using [^A-Za-z _]? [^A-Za-z] is fine, ri8? 2) We should use df['description'] = df['description'].str.replace('[^A-Za-z _]',' ') instead of df['description'] = df['description'].str.replace('[^A-Za-z _]','')...ri8? (last parameter changed to ' ' from ''.)